# oauth2 auth on SPA based on Angular.js + Node.js/PassportJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Which is a common way to implement oauth2 auth on the angular-based single page application?
Is it possible to implement it without page reload? If not - what is a best way to transfer auth data back to angular code from the page?

Answer (score 1):

The authorization server must provide an api to authenticate user and return access token ***without*** redirecting. I will take facebook as authorization server and resource server in this example for easier understanding. The flow is like this:

1. Your user clicks on a button on the page.
2. Since this is SPA built with angularjs, the browser sends an ajax to
   your server to get data.
3. On server side, you find out that this action requires data from
   resource server (facebook), ***instead of redirecting*** the browser
   to resource server as we usually do, the server sends a response
   with a custom status (or any information indicating that this action
   needs an access token) to the browser.
4. On browser, when you receive response from server in your ajax
   success callback function. You can check the response and find out
   that this action needs an access token
5. The browser first tries to get this access token from resource server
   (if the user is already logged in). When working with facebook using
   FB javascript SDK, we usually use [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) function.

   a. If we can get the access token in the success callback (the user is
   already logged in), just send this access token to server to get
   data (using ajax).

   b. If the user is not logged in yet, use javascript
   to prompt the user to login by rendering a login button and the user has to click on it. When working with facebook using FB
   javascript SDK, we usually use [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) function when user clicks on the login button. After
   successful login, we will receive the access token in the success
   callback and just send it to server to get the response (using
   ajax).

There is no page reload because all actions are done with ajax (without browser's redirects)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Could you please clarify a bit point 3. I do not understand how to make it without page redirecting. Because we need to be redirected to facebook page, to be able to allow use our data for the application.

Comment: @silent_coder: in point 3, your server only needs to return a normal response like in any other ajax requests to your server (but with information to indicate this action needs access token). On client side, you receive this response in your ajax success callback function (in step 4) and create subsequent ajax requests to facebook.

Comment: I think you do not understand the process. When you using some oAuth2 provder, like facebook, when you send initial request to facebook to asking permission, then your application redirects to facebook page, where you could allow or deny using some account related data, and then facebook redirects you to the callback page. That is the general oAuth2 workflow. So I do not understand how to make it with ajax and your answer do not describe it.

Comment: @silent_coder: we do redirect the user to FB, but in a `popup window`, not our main page. Quote from the doc: `Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.` When the user finishes login we will get the response (access token,..) in the success callback.

Comment: @silent_coder: please check out the docs and some examples in the links in my answer

Comment: I do not use facebook JS sdk, I use passportjs, but anyway I'll check it, probably it have something similar.

Comment: But the difference is that passport operate on the serverside.

Comment: I think I'm get the idea, but it's not ajax of course. Popup open in new window, which then reload with callback information.